# Do I need SSL certificates on an application server?

Tags: ssl, proxypass

I have a 3-tier deployment (webserver, application, database). I have applied an SSL certificate on the webserver (Apache). There is another application on the appserver that is PHP-based. Requests for this application are routed from the webserver via a ProxyPass directive in the `virtualhost.conf` file.

When I request the application from the application-server, I get a "mixedcontent" error (http content served over https connections).

My question(s):
1. Do I need an SSL certificate on the application server?
2. How do I get this error to go away?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, you need an SSL certificate on the application server as soon as you want to establish a secure connection.
2. Install a certificate on the application server and add virtual host settings for this server like this:

   `<VirtualHost *:443>`

   ```
     ServerName app.yourdomain.tld

     SSLProxyEngine On
     ProxyPass / https://app.yourdomain.tld/
     ProxyPassReverse / https://app.yourdomain.tld/
   ```

   `</VirtualHost>`

The Problem is that your secure website probably has its own domain name and you try to embed code from that in your https site. In this case the browser warns the user that parts of the connection aren't encrypted.

You can try this out with a free certificate first, like StartSSL.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The thing is, my application server is not open to the internet and does not have a domain name. What is the FQDN for which I will get and apply a certificate?

Comment: How exactly do you request content from your app-server and what kind of content do you request?

Comment: Content is requested via `ProxyPass`. The content is simple HTML and audio files.

Answer (score 0):

This could occur if you mix http and https in your code, I think that you would benefit from reading through the following article:
[How To Geek article](http://www.howtogeek.com/181911/htg-explains-what-exactly-is-a-mixed-content-warning/)